# Length of the Union of Intervals is less than the Sum of Each Length of Intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading Royden and Fitzpatrick's book on Real Analysis, and I have a question about the length function on an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that given $\{I_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of countable collection of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$:

$$ \ell( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ell (I_n)? $$

Where $\ell$ is the length function? It think this was implicitly used in their proof that the outer measure $m^*$ has the subadditivity property. I think it is true though, since, each $I_n$ might not be pairwise disjoint.

Comment: How is $\ell$ defined?

Comment: The difference between the endpoints of a bounded interval (if I understand it right, it does not matter if the interval is closed or open, or semi-open), and I think it should be infinite when the interval is unbounded. For each open set, the "length" of an open set will be the sum of the lengths of the countable number of open intervals of which it is composed.

Comment: This isn't completely correct, and neither is the approved proof. It is true if $I$ is an **interval** covered by the open sets that $\ell(I) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ell (I_n)$. But, the length is only defined for an interval, being the difference between the endpoints. So $\ell( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n})$ is in general not defined.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1432225 for correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1. Make the system of intervals disjoint and show that equality holds.
2. Then, realize that the length of what you've removed must have been positive.

---

To make the system disjoint, you may let

$$E_0 := I_0,$$
$$E_1 := I_1 - I_0,$$
$$E_2 := I_2 - (I_0 \cup I_1),$$

that is for $k > 1$

$$E_k := I_k - (I_1 \cup \cdots \cup I_{k-1}).$$

For the disjoint system, observe that equality holds (you "don't count anything twice").

Comment: Do I not need to show that $\ell $ has the property of monotonity for this? That is, if $A,B$ are open intervals, and $A \subset B$, then $\ell (A) \leq \ell (B)$?

Comment: Yes, but for two open intervals $A$ and $B$ such that $A \subset B$, this should be simple, right?

Comment: I think I can prove that by rewriting $B = A \cup (B-A)$.

We then have, for that pairwise disjoint set, $\ell( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_{n}) =\ell( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ell (E_n)  \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ell (I_n).$ Since each $E_n \subset I_n$.

Comment: Yes, but the end should read "Since each ${\mathcal l}(E_n) \le {\mathcal l}(I_n)$", right?

Comment: Does that not follow from monotonicity?

Comment: Sure, it does, except your previous version of the comment read $\dots \le \dots$, so I assumed it was a syntax error.

Comment: See my comment on the question.